# localization strategies of vanilla JS web components [customElement v1]

Tags: javascript, html, localization, web-component

While building very generic and reusable vanilla JS based web components, I am stuck with the localization part.

For very simple components, which are getting their text via attributes, it is no problem, as the text provided should already be in the desired language.

```
# label in English
<raised-button lable="Add Products"></raised-button>
# Arabic
<raised-button lable="أضف منتجات"></raised-button>
```

Problem is when the component is bit more complicated and it can have its own messages etc

```
<strong-password></strong-password>
```

this component check the password input and displays messages like 
You need at least one uppercase, one lowercase and one integer. [default , english]

But to make this component universally usable, it should be able to adapt to the lang of the page it is being used in.

One ideas that I have in mind is to add lang as an attribute. just like html tag

```
<strong-password lang='en'></strong-password>
```

Second option, inside the component, use JS to check if `<html lang>` is set, then automatically use the html tag language.
This approach looks a bit weird though because component javascript seems like going out of its scope to reach to the very parent tag.

As web components are becoming popular, I am sure there is already some standard way to solve it.

Can a component know the language of the `surrounding` somehow ?